# Could not convert string to float: ...Sometimes

Tags: python, zip

I'm having some strange things happen when converting strings to floats in a loop.

So when I use the following code exactly it writes:

```
[1468436874000, 0.00254071495719],
[1468528803000, 0.00341349353996],
[1468688596000, 0.000853373384991],
[1468871365000, 0.00256012015497],
```

It stops short, there should be about 30 lines more than that and those are the wrong calculations.

The function is:

```
def main():

minprice = pricelist('MIN')
maxprice = pricelist('MAX')
avgprice = pricelist('AVG')
avgsqft = sqftlist()
datelist = getdates()
index = fileparser()

with open('/home/andrew/Desktop/index3.htm', 'w') as file:

    file.writelines(data[:index[0]])

    for date, minprice, maxprice in zip(datelist, minprice, maxprice):
        file.writelines('[%s, %s, %s],\n' % (date, minprice, maxprice))

    file.writelines(data[index[1]:index[2]])

    for date, avgprice in zip(datelist, avgprice):
        file.writelines('[%s, %s],\n' % (date, avgprice))

    file.writelines(data[index[3]:index[4]])

    for date, avgprice, avgsqft in zip(datelist, avgprice, avgsqft):
        file.writelines('[%s, %s],\n' % (date, ((float(avgprice))/(float(avgsqft)))))

    file.writelines(data[index[5]:])
    file.close()
```

The error is:

```
file.writelines('[%s, %s],\n' % (date, ((float(avgprice))/(float(avgsqft)))))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: .
```

Oddly, when I comment out the other for loops before it, the result is:

```
[1468436874000, 2.82644376127],
[1468528803000, 2.86702735915],
[1468688596000, 2.8546107764],
[1468871365000, 2.8546107764],
[1468871996000, 2.8546107764],
[1468919656000, 2.85383420662],
[1469004050000, 2.85189704903],
[1469116491000, 2.87361540168],
[1469189815000, 2.86059636119],
[1469276601000, 2.83694745621],
[1469367041000, 2.83903252711],
[1469547497000, 2.83848688853],
[1469649630000, 2.83803033196],
[1469736031000, 2.82327110329],
[1469790030000, 2.82650020338],
[1469876430000, 2.96552660866],
[1470022624000, 2.93407180385],
```

Moreover, when I use enumerate instead of zip (and make the appropriate changes), it works. I've examined both lists at the fifth item for anything unusual because that's where it's getting hung up, but there is nothing odd there in either list. Since it does work fine with enumerate I'll just do that for now. But I'm new to Python/programming in general and want to understand what exactly is causing this.

***UPDATE*** Should have included this the first time.

```
#     file.writelines(data[:index[0]+1])
#     for date, minprice, maxprice in zip(datelist, minprice, maxprice):
#         file.writelines('[%s, %s, %s],\n' % (date, minprice, maxprice))
#     file.writelines(data[index[1]:index[2]+1])
#     for date, avgprice in zip(datelist, avgprice):
#         file.writelines('[%s, %s],\n' % (date, avgprice))
#     file.writelines(data[index[3]:index[4]+1])
#     time.sleep(1)
for date, avgprice, avgsqft in zip(datelist, avgprice, avgsqft):
    # file.writelines(
    print'[%s, %s],\n' % (date, ((float(avgprice))/(float(avgsqft))))
    # file.writelines(data[index[5]:])
    # file.close()
```

Prints... (correctly)

```
[1468436874000, 2.82644376127],

[1468528803000, 2.86702735915],

[1468688596000, 2.8546107764],

[1468871365000, 2.8546107764],

[1468871996000, 2.8546107764],

[1468919656000, 2.85383420662],

etc...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debug by printing the values of `avgprice` and `avgsqft` in your code. You are getting some `string` as it's value which can not be converted to float

Comment: I've tried that and didn't see anything odd around the 4th-5th item. Would that explain why it only doesn't work this one way?

Comment: What are the last `avgprice` and `avgsqft` values that your code is printing?

Comment: Hmm. Printing avgprice and avgsqft in the loop printed 3 1180.77 4 1171.82 1 1171.82 3 1171.82 . *ERROR* So basically it's iterating for each character of the price and getting an error at the decimal, which explains why it prints a few wrong numbers then stops. I'm not sure why this works differently when the other two loops are commented out though. Any ideas?

Comment: I figured it out. I didn't understand how exactly zip in a loop would change the lists passed into it. Basically after passing the avgprice list into the loop with zip, at the end, it was a string with only the last item in the list 3413.xx in it. So the next loop iterated through that number. Thanks for your help though, I didn't think of printing avgprice at ever point in the function to see where it changed.